# Map and Hashmap with scanner in java. How to delete an entry

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I'm having a hard time in doing this Map and HashMap in java since I'm still learning about it. So we have this activity and I'm halfway done with it, and my problem is I don't know How to delete a mapping on the entry in java. Does anyone have any idea how to do it. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class StudentList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
Map<String,String> Student = new HashMap<>();

for (int i=1;i<=3;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter student number " + i + ": ");
    String num = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter first name " + i + ": ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    Student.put(num,name);
}
System.out.println("Student List:");
for(Map.Entry List:Student.entrySet())
    System.out.println(List.getKey()+ "  " +List.getValue());
}
}
//This is the output of it.   
Enter student number 1: 0004
Enter first name 1: Mary
Enter student number 2: 0018
Enter first name 2: Nica
Enter student number 3: 0145
Enter first name 3: Mae
Student List:
0018  Nica   // I also have a problem here, idk why Nica is 1st on the list and not Mary.
0004  Mary
0145  Marc

//This is the part of the instruction in our activity.
The output shall:
-Ask three (3) of your classmates to enter their student number (key) and first name (value).
-Display the keys and values of the map.
-Delete the mapping of the third entry
-Enter your student number and first name. This would be the new third entry.        
-Display the entries in separate lines.
```

Answer (score 2):

## `Map#remove`

To remove an entry (the key-value pair) from a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), call [`Map#remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) while passing the key.

In your case, your keys are `Integer` objects (boxed versions of your `int` primitive values). So if you want to delete the entry for the key of `3`:

```
String nameValueOfEntryRemoved = map.remove( 3 ) ;
```

You might want to check the return value for being `null` or not.

## Iteration order

You also asked:

> why Nica is 1st on the list and not Mary

Why would you expect Mary to be first? The [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) class you used made no such promise. To quote the first paragraph of its Javadoc:

> … This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

If you care about keeping the keys in order, use a [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) implementation or a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation.

If you want the keys kept in original insertion order, use an implementation such as [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Here is a graphic chart I made to help you in choosing a `Map` implementation.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]